# meaning of 'sold' in the context

Tags: meaning

Here is the context from a novel 'Angels and Demons' by Dan Brown. I know 'sold' is the past tense of sell, but here, I think the word has another meaning.

> Vittoria sounded only slightly more hopeful. "I suppose Galileo could have created some sort of mathematical code that went unnoticed by the clergy."
>   "You don't sound sold," Langdon said, moving down the row.

Comment: For the record, it’s standard English style to *italicize* (or underline, when hand-writing) the titles of books, such as *Angels and Demons*. (And on Stack Exchange, you can italicize by surrounding the text with asterisks `*`.)

Comment: @KRyan the wonderful thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from.

Comment: If he was trying to sell her the idea, and she bought it, then she would be sold (as would the idea), but she doesn't sound like she bought it.

Comment: @KRyan Quotation marks are a perfectly reasonable way to set titles.

Answer (score 15):

"You don't sound *convinced*" is a clearer expression of the ideas, but *sold* is a colloquialism.

One trying to persuade another of an idea can be said to be selling the idea. If a person doesn't sound *sold* [on it] then they haven't *bought* it, and don't accept it enough to make a commitment.

Answer (score 11):

*Sold* in this context means:

> uncritically attached to or enthusiastic about

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sold

It's often used in the form *sold on* as in:

> I'm **sold on** the idea.

Langdon is saying that Vittoria is not yet willing to accept his statement as true. She might at some point in the future, but would require more convincing.